# RHEL: selinux blocking blocking to start kickstart

Tags: rhel5, selinux, tftp

I am having issue when I select a kick start profile to start installation after PXE boot. On the network installation server (same DHCP server) side I can see the following error in /var/log/messages when I hit this issue.

```
Nov 13 17:42:30 desktop10 dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:0c:29:90:39:53 via eth0
Nov 13 17:42:30 desktop10 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.174.2 to 00:0c:29:90:39:53 via eth0
Nov 13 17:42:32 desktop10 dhcpd: Dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.174.2.
Nov 13 17:42:32 desktop10 dhcpd: Remove host declaration desktopy or remove 192.168.174.2
Nov 13 17:42:32 desktop10 dhcpd: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.174/24
Nov 13 17:42:32 desktop10 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.174.2 (192.168.174.10) from 00:0c:29:90:39:53 via eth0
Nov 13 17:42:32 desktop10 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.174.2 to 00:0c:29:90:39:53 via eth0
Nov 13 17:42:32 desktop10 in.tftpd[20546]: tftp: client does not accept options
Nov 13 17:42:36 desktop10 setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing in.tftpd (tftpd_t) "read" to ./vmlinuz (httpd_sys_content_t). For complete SELinux messages. run sealert -l 97c61847-7ea2-435f-bede-c95302b034f5**
```

On server the the selinux security contents

```
[root@desktop10 ~]# ls -Z /tftpboot/images/ks-rhel-x86_64-server-6-60/vmlinuz
-rw-r--r--  apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /tftpboot/images/ks-rhel-x86_64-server-6-60/vmlinuz
```

Note: desktop10 is RHEL5.6, if I change selinux to permissive then I can proceed with installation.

Can someone help me to sort out this issue? Please let me know if anyone need more info.

---

Tried as suggested in the comment but no luck

```
  [root@desktop10 ~]# restorecon -Rv /tftpboot/
  [root@desktop10 ~]# ls -Z /tftpboot/images/ks-rhel-x86_64-server-6-60/vmlinuz
  -rw-r--r--  apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /tftpboot/images/ks-rhel-x86_64-server-6-60/vmlinuz
```

Answer (score 0):

Your files are labeled by 'httpd_sys_content_t' that is not acceptable label for kickstart. It looks you copied the file from an apache directory or you create the file from a web appliaction running on apache.

Relabel directory by default labels:

```
[root@localhost /]# restorecon -Rv /tftpboot
```

Comment: Tried but no luck. edited my original question and left the output in the bottom of the question. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Could you add results of 'semanage fcontext -l | grep tftp' command, please? It is helpful to see your default SELinux labeling.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may work if you try to relabel the directory with tftpd context tftpd_rw_t:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t tftpd_rw_t '/tftpboot(/.*)?'
# restorecon -R -v /tftpboot
```